# How to Update tables based on self join

Tags: sql, oracle

Update table based on self join on customer_po = ID

**Table XYZ**

```
ID     Invoice Date   Delivery_date  Customer_po
123    01-01-2018     null           null               
125    10-01-2018     null           123
```

I want Output record like below in Oracle SQL

```
ID     Invoice Date   Delivery_date  Customer_po
123    01-01-2018     01-01-2018     null
125    10-01-2018     01-01-2018     123
```

Comment: Delivery_date column and corrected customer_po

Comment: So why has `customer_po` changed in the expected output?

Comment: This makes no sense

Comment: sorry, i have corrected, I want to update delivery date same as the invoice date of customer_po=123

Comment: This still makes no sense. Do you want to change *all* delivery dates? Or all delivery dates that are null? Or delivery dates of certain customers? Or something else still? And you say you want the delivery date to match customer 123's invoice date. But their invoice date is 10-01-2018, while your result delivery dates are 01-01-2018.

Comment: It should look up for customer_po and check the ID = 123 ( i.e. self join on ID = Customer_po) then get the set the delivery_date = invoice_date

Comment: So why did delivery date change for id `123`? That row has no value for `customer_po` so no join is possible, yet it still changed from `null` to `01-01-2018`.

Answer (score 1):

You need an update statement like this.

```
UPDATE xyz
   SET Delivery_date =
          (SELECT MAX (invoice_date)
             FROM xyz
            WHERE Customer_po = 123);
```

Note that I have used `MAX` to avoid the errors due to multiple values for `Customer_po = 123`